# Converting from TXT to Array Error with List of Lists

Tags: python, csv

I want to convert a .txt file into a numpy array, but I am receiving the following error:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
In [29]: with open('file.txt') as f:
    ...:     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    ...:     d = list(reader)
    ...:     d = np.array(d)
    ...: col1 = d[:,0]
    ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-61025b336d31> in <module>()
      4     import numpy as np
      5     d = np.array(d)
----> 6 col1 = d[:,0]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

The format for d is the following:

```
In [30]: d
Out[30]:
array([list(['AF', 'AAUS', '9.0349', '38.766499', '2437.800049', 'Addis Ababa University, Ethiopia', '2006-01-10T00:00:00', ''])], dtype=object)
```

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong, as I can't index this array of lists.  What workaround would you suggest to fix this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't `import numpy` inside of your `with` block. Import it once at the top of your file

Comment: Noted.  Original issue still stands.

Answer (score -2):

Show the content of `file.txt` please.

And you can load array from a local file with `numpy.loadtxt` (csv is unnecessary) :

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html